# How to understand point functions

Tags: functions, metric-spaces

I am having trouble understanding the meaning of point functions. I know the mathematical definition but i don't think that i truly understand there true meaning.

Point functions:

Suppose $(X,d)$ is a metric space and $z∈X$. Then a nonnegative real function

$x \rightarrow d(x,z)$ defined on $X$ is a point function at $z$.

I have tried looking for examples w/ no luck.

Comment: I never heard of point functions but the function you defined there, gives the distance between x and z in the metric of X. How are those point functions used in your text?

Comment: From your link, they're just saying that if you know the point function at $0$ you can recover the entire metric using the fact that subtraction is defined in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Was that part clear? What kind of examples are you looking for? The author is just using this as an interesting example.

Answer (score 0):

By your description, it seems that given a point $z \in X$, the point function $\delta_z(x)$ returns the distance between $x$ and $z$.

For example, in $\mathbb{R}$, let $\delta_0$ be a point function at $0$. Then $\delta_0(3)$ would be equivalent to $d(3,0)$, or the distance between $3$ and $0$, which is $3$. Similarly, let $\delta_8$ be a point function at $8$. Then $\delta_8(3) = d(3,8) = 5$.

Please elaborate on what you mean by “I don’t think that I truly understand there [*sic*; should be ‘their’] true meaning.”